# How do I store a mongoose schema in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing an special app with express and mongoose that needs to build a mongoose schema and then store it in database. I want to create a project that people can create collections dynamically at run time and then ask the others to fill those collections via special forms

For example I would like to store a schema such as the one below into my database. How can I do that?

```
var entitySchema = {
    name : String,
    num : [Number],
    time : [Date]
} ;
```

Is there any special function that converts mongoose schemas to json or string?
calling **toString()** function on the schema json, does not work, because it can't interpret the **String** or **Number** types

Comment: Uhm, what? You want to store the Schema ***in*** the database? Well, it's just an object, so that shouldn't be an issue, but why on earth would you need to, this seems like a horrible idea all together ?

Comment: I want to create a project that people can create collections dynamically at run time and then ask the others to fill those collections via special forms, thats why  I need to store the schema in DB

Comment: Does the save method work? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save

Comment: You could always store the schema with `{name : "", num: 1}` etc. and call `.constructor` on the values in a loop after getting it to get the constructors back before passing it into Mongo. Haven't tried it, but should work. However this is all wrong, schemas shouldn't be dynamic, and you shouldn't let users define the schemas at all.

Comment: @Salar - were you able to get this up and running?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose schemas use function propreties like `Date` and its own types such as `Schema.Types.Mixed` to define schemas, and MongoDB won't know how to store such things, so you'll have to do some additional serialization/deserialization legwork to make that work. For example, converting functions into strings when saving the schema eg Date-->"Date" and restoring the proper Date function back again when reading the schema back to mongoose. You would need to recurse through your schema structure to look for problematic properties and make such modifications. This is doable but there are other perhaps better options if you don't need the extra funcionality that mongoose offers (like index generation, pre/post middleware, etc).

You might consider using [JSON schemas](http://json-schema.org/) instead. A popular library for this is [tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4).

JSON schemas can be stored in mongoDB without changes and you can use the same schema lib on both the client and server. JSON schema parsing engines also give you more options with respect to validation, such as better error messages.